# Feeding a PHP array into a Javascript Array/Drop Down

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a webpage that has drop downs populated by values supplied by an Oracle database query.
The code I'm using is what has worked for me before when querying Sql Server, but modified for Oracle.
This is really outside of my skillset - I'm more of a Sys Admin than developer: but it's just one of those cases where there is no one else to do it.
This is the PHP code that queries Oracle (the var_dump was to erify that the array is populated with values form Oracle):

```
**<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_pconnect("user", "password", "//oracleserver/prod");
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT terms_cd from terms ORDER BY terms_cd';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);
$j = 0;
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
             $termscode[] = array("id" => $j, "val" => $item);
        $j++;
        }
    }

    //Verify Array
    //var_dump($termscode);
   $jsonTermsCode = json_encode($termscode);
 ?>**
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
<?php>
    echo "var termscode = $jsonTermsCode; \n";
?>
    function loadTermsCode()
    {
        var select1 = document.getElementById("termscodeSelect");
        for(var i = 0; i < termscode.length; i++)
        {
            var Terms = document.createElement("option");
            //Terms.text = termscode[i];
            //Select1.add(Terms, null);
            select1.options[i] = new Option(termscode[i].val, termscode[i].id);
            echo select1.options[i]  
        }
    }   
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<body onload="loadFunc(), loadTermsCode()">
    <form id="f" method="post" name="VendorChange" >

<!--Div 1-->
    <div id="container">

    <!--Div 2-->
    <div id="divTabContainer">


               <fieldset>       
                <table>
                        <td class="dept">
                            Terms Code:
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="termscodeSelect" name="TermCode" >
                            </select>
                        </td>   

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>     
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The drop down does not populate - I've been beating my head on this and just can't figure out why.
Any insight?

Comment: Where does the `loadFunc()` function come into play, or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Does the code correctly connect to the database? Is the query correctly executed? The `var_dump` contains the right values?

Comment: small hint: There is no `echo` in JavaScript

Comment: You have an `>` in your JS `<?php>` <= that will break your PHP. So, do `<?php` - Plus, add error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

the "echo" you have inside your javascript must be causing you an error. to "echo" something in javascript you need "document.Write()".

besides that, the code you have commented out seems to be correct based on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp except for the index being NULL. simply ignore the index if you dont want to assign one.

i am referring to the code:

```
var Terms = document.createElement("option");
Terms.text = termscode[i];
Select1.add(Terms);
```

Comment: don't use `document.write`, especially not after the document has fully loaded.

Comment: do you have any other way of "echo"ing text via javascript?